# Apereo CAS - login through REST call

Tags: java, rest, cas, apereo

I have a cas server running localy (https://localhost:8443) and a default user.
Username: casuser
Password: Mellon

I want to use another java based application to login a user by using Apero CAS.

Is it possible to call a Apereo CAS API for the login from another application and get back some kind of validation (token) if the login is successful?

It would be best if i can for example just send the username and password as a json format and get back a response regarding if the login was successful or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that via the CAS REST protocol: https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.6.x/protocol/REST-Protocol.html but you will lose the SSO (Single-Sign-On) feature.

You'd better stick to the webflow login process: https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.6.x/protocol/CAS-Protocol.html